# Ranking based on Weighted Average for multiple criteria

Tags: python, math

Given a list of cars and their top speeds, MPG and car cost.
I want to rank them. With Speed a 'weight' of 50%, MPG 'weight' of 30% and car cost 20%.

The faster the car, the better..
The higher the MPG, the better...
The lower the COST, the better...

What formula can I use to rank the cars in order, based on this criteria?

So given this list.  How can I rank them?

```
CAR     SPEED      MPG      COST 
A        135       20       50,000
B        150       15       60,000
C        170       18       80,000
D        120       30       40,000
```

What software library can i use to do this ?  Python? Numpy?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a Python library called "pandas", where you can manipulate your data, Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.read_csv("your_csv_file.csv")
df['SCORE'] = (df['MPG'] / df['MPG'].max() * 50) + (df['SPEED'] / df['SPEED'].max() * 30) + (df['COST'].max() / df['COST'] * 20)
df = df.sort_values(by=['SCORE'], ascending=False)
```

It creates a new column with its associated score:

```
  CAR  SPEED  MPG  COST       SCORE
3   D    120   30  40.0  111.176471
0   A    135   20  50.0   89.156863
2   C    170   18  80.0   80.000000
1   B    150   15  60.0   78.137255
```

Comment: Iterating over rows like that is highly discouraged. Pandas (and numpy, and the entire scipy ecosystem) are tuned for vectorized operations.

Comment: Thx. Does this take into account that MPG is a low number and speed and cost are high?  'Apples vs. Oranges'?

Answer (score 1):

You can score the different rows with simple arithmetic. Since `COST` is inversely proportioned, we'll consider `1/COST` instead. If `COST` can ever be zero, you could also subtract it instead of use the inverse.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CAR': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'SPEED': [135, 150, 170, 120],
                   'MPG': [20, 15, 18, 30],
                   'COST': [50.0, 60.0, 80.0, 40.0]})


score = 0.5*df["SPEED"] + 0.3*df["MPG"] + 0.2/df["COST"]
df.loc[score.sort_values(ascending=False).index]

  CAR  SPEED  MPG  COST
2   C    170   18  80.0
1   B    150   15  60.0
0   A    135   20  50.0
3   D    120   30  40.0
```

Comment: Your ranking is WRONG. You can't calculate score by adding Apples (Speed) to Oranges (MPG) etc. First, you need to rank SPEED, MPG and COST separately and after that calculate the score and final rank: `FinalRank = Rank(0.5 * Rank(SPEED) + 0.3 * Rank(MPG) + 0.2 * DescendingRank(COST))`.